# Custom serializer not getting invoked in Spring Boot (Jackson 2.13.3)

Tags: jackson, customserializer

I'm working on a REST API project that uses Spring Boot. Each REST API call should return NULL values as empty strings so that the UI developer can display the values as is.

I was not able to find a Jackson annotation to convert NULLs to empty strings during serialization. Hence I wrote a custom serializer, but it is not working as expected. If you look at the code below, the sysout stmt in the custom serializer i.e. "in date serializer" is not getting printed. So it appears that the customserializer is not even getting invoked.

I'm using Jackson 2.13.3.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="hlr_vw")
@Immutable
public class Healer_Flattened implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "hlr_id")
    private Integer healerId;
    
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class) 
    @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat(pattern="YYYY-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "hlr_brth_dt")
    private Date dob;
    
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomStringSerializer.class) 
    @Column(name = "hlr_rsdnc_city")
    private String city;
        
    // getters & setters 
}
```

REST controller method:

```java
@GetMapping("/healers/search")
public List<Healer_Flattened> searchHealers(@Param("fname") String fname, @Param("city") String city, @Param("lngId") String lngId) throws JsonProcessingException {
        
    System.out.println("fname=" + fname);
    List<Healer_Flattened> hf = healerFlattenedRepo.findByFirstName(fname);
    System.out.println(hf.get(0).getFirstName());
    System.out.println("dob before serialization=" + hf.get(0).getDob());
    String serialized = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(hf.get(0));
    System.out.println("After serialization=" + serialized);

    // ...
}
```

This is my custom serializer:

```java
public class CustomSerializer extends StdSerializer<Date> {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
    
    public CustomSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }
    
    public CustomSerializer(Class<Date> t) { 
        super(t); 
    } 
     
    @Override 
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException { 
        System.out.println("in date serializer"); // doesn't print
        generator.writeStartObject();   
        generator.writeString(value==null?"":value.toString()); 
        generator.writeEndObject();
    } 
}
```

`CustomStringSerializer` is similar.

Log output:

```
2023-09-11 22:41:13.494 TRACE 17616 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [admin]
```

After serialization I have:

> {"healerId":0,"dob":null,"city":null,"firstName":"admin","lastName":"admin","emailId":"adm.sai.55@gmail.com","acceptNewCaseFlag":null,"maxNumberOfCases":null,"languagesSpoken":null}

If any of you can help me and tell me what is wrong with the code below, I would appreciate it.

Comment: It appears you're expecting the serialization to happen during DB insert and update. JPA doesn't care about Jackson. If you want stuff to happen before insert, you need to use JPA hooks.

Comment: No, Abhijit, I'm not expecting anything to happen during a DB insert or update. As I mentioned in the description, I'm issuing a REST API call and I don't want any of the fields to have null in the JSON Response. In the code snippet shown above, the dob and city have null values in the database. Hence I'm getting a null value in these fields when using the healerFlattenedRepo.findByFirstName(fname) JPA method.

Comment: Since I don't want to see null values in the JSON response, I tried to use a custom serializer.

Comment: Why did you do that? To overcome the code percentage limit in the question, you posted half the code as text.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see any option to attach the code. I didn't get any error when pasting the code. Stackoverflow just asked me to ident the code when trying to post the question and I did that. Going forward, I will check in the code to GIT and paste the link here. Sorry again.

Comment: Please refer to the link below. It appears that the StdSerializer.serialize method will not accept a null value. Since the value was null in my case, the serialize method was not even called. I tested with a non null value for the dob field and the custom serializer serialize method was invoked  - https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/StdSerializer.html#serialize(T,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider)

Comment: I suggested changes to your question to make it easier for the community to read. This will help you to find someone who can solve your problem. Additional github links in questions are not appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer

For customize `null`-serialization you should use the `nullsUsing` property:

```java
@JsonSerialize(nullsUsing = CustomSerializer.class)
```

Based on the docs, this is what you need:

> Serializer class to use for serializing nulls for properties that are annotated, instead of the default null serializer. Note that using this property when annotation types (classes) has no effect currently (it is possible this could be improved in future).
> Since:
> 2.3

##### CustomSerializer

Note that you must not use methods `writeStartObject()` and `writeEndObject()` in your serializer. These methods are used to write `{` and `}` to describe a JSON object.

#### A few words about another approach

Using an application logic entity as a domain transfer object is not a common approach. I think you should separate these objects.

What I mean?

Your `Healer_Flattened` class is a private entity of your application. And you want to provide that class through REST API. It is not a good idea, because it is make your application inflexible and dangerous for consumers of your REST API.

For example, if you change `Healer_Flattened` the data provided by the REST API will be automatically changed for consumers which cannot expect those changes, or you will have to pay extra effort to avoid providing your internal changes to API consumers using `@JsonIgnore` or something else.

To avoid these annoying problems the DTOs are commonly used.

```java
public class HealerFlattenedDto {
    private Integer healerId;
    private Date dob;
    private String city;
        
    // getters & setters 
}
```

Insted of using `Healer_Flattened`, you can use `HealerFlattenedDto` to provide data to API consumers. You can change this class as you wish.

Comment: Thanks Maksim. We can register the custom serializer with the class directly using the @JsonSerialize annotation instead of registering with object mapper. Please see this link - https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization.   As I mentioned in my previous comment, the custom serializer serialize method does get invoked for non-null values. It is not getting invoked when the field has a null value. The documentation that I shared says that a null value cannot be passed to the serialize method. This does not solve my problem though. Thanks a lot for the DTO tip, I will fix my code.

Comment: @Sara I got you. I think there is a way out

Comment: @Sara I have updated my answer and added a working solution

Comment: Thanks a lot, Maksim. I tried it and it works. Sharing the link for the documentation so that it benefits others - https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html